# Using threads to update UI with Swift

Tags: xcode, multithreading, swift, xcode6

I'm developing a software with Xcode 6 using Swift. When I press a button, my code takes some informations from the web and writes them on my NSWindow.

So imagine something like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    for page in listOfPages                     //Number of pages is 40.
    {
        var label: NSTextField = NSTextField();

        label.stringValue = getInformetionsFromPage(page)

        /*
             some code to add label in the window here 
        */ 
    }
}
```

The problem is that once I click the button, it takes a while before I see the list of results, in the main time the app is frozen. That's because I'm not using any threads to handle this problem. How could I implement threads to see every label updated every step of the loop? I'm new with threads and Swift, so I would need some help!

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html). Here is a basic usage:

```
for page in listOfPages {
    var label = NSTextField()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        let result = getInformationFromPage(page)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            label.stringValue = result
        }
    }
}
```

`dispatch_async` function asynchronously runs the block of code on the given queue. In first `dispatch_async` call we dispatch the code to run on background queue. After we get `result` we update label on main queue with that `result`

Comment: Excellent! I have just a doubt, here in your code where should I set the frame of the label in the window? Before the third line?

Comment: I don't know if it is true for cocoa but in cocoa touch you should never access ui code on other than main thread. So before the first dispatch and inside second dispatch block it is safe to access ui code

Answer (score 56):

**Swift 3.0 + version**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    // your UI update code
}
```

Posted this because XCode cannot suggest the correct syntax from swift 2.0 version